# Web Forms For Marketers Save Actions Not Executing

Tags: wffm

In my instance of Sitecore 7.5, no Save Actions are being executed for WFFM.  This is not related to custom save actions- no save actions are executing, even the default ones.

I have tested by completely breaking the `<successAction>` pipeline in *Sitecore.Forms.config*.  I added a processor with a namespace/assembly that is blatantly wrong, yet no matter what I do, I always receive the Success Message on the form.  I have tried with numerous default actions.  I've also gone so far as to brick the namespaces on those actions, and yet I still receive the success message- so clearly it is completely bypassing them.  I reverted all code and configs to the native Sitecore install and a WFFM install.  I pushed the required DLLs from my solution to get the site up and running- no other modules or 3rd party code is running.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After pulling out my non-existant hair, I decided to decompile the *Sitecore.Forms.Core.dll*.  Lowe and behold, there is a check in `FormsHandler.cs` if the site is not in `DisplayMode.Normal` to ignore all save actions.

In our particular case, the entire site is hidden behind the Sitecore login, therefore to test, it is our common practice to login to Sitecore, then preview the site.  *Previewing* the site sets this flag to `DisplayMode.Preview`, thus causing all save actions to be ignored.

Appending `sc_mode=normal` to the query string properly sets the flag to `DisplayMode.Normal` and allows all save actions to execute.

I found no other posts about this anywhere, hopefully this helps someone some day.

Comment: great find. please mark this as the answer. you can mark your own asnwers.

Comment: I know, but I cannot do it for two days after posting.